# Do different tabs on the same website use the same connection?

Tags: sockets, browser, websocket, connection

I was wondering how multiple connections to the same website to access different pages is carried out? For example, in Chrome, if you were to go to Google then open another tab and go to Google would the same connection be used for both pages? If not how is this normally handled?

Answer (score 1):

It is the same internet connection (from your computer), but two different HTTP requests using that connection, using two different ports from your computer (going to the same port at the destination).  Your web browser uses a different port for each tab.  But the request goes to the same port at the destination (usually port 80).

Also, please realize, that when you bring up Google in a browser, you are not "connected" to that web page.  The request is made, and the page content is returned to your computer.  When we speak of "connection", it usually means the computer's method of accessing the internet (Ethernet, wireless, etc).